# Are manipulations with strings expensive in Redis?

Tags: json, string, performance, redis, lua

I am quite new to Redis and Lua. I have some scripts where small json objects are stored in hashes. In Lua script I get the string json object and append more properties to it by this way:

`postJson = postJson:gsub('}', ', "count":' .. commentsCount .. ' }')`

Also to get certain properties of the object I do `cjson.decode(postJson)['TitleId']`

The question is are these manipulations expensive and is there a better way of doing things mentioned above?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Redis doesn’t modify strings/data; all it does is store and retrieve. Are you actually asking if string manipulation and/or json parsing is expensive in lua?  If so, how you store strings (in your case using Redis) is irrelevant to the question, which should be modified to remove all references to Redis.

Comment: Where are Lua scripts run then? I believe Lua scripts are loaded and run in Redis, right?

Comment: [The doc](https://redis.io/commands/eval) says the Lua 5.1  interpreter is built into Redis from version 2.6.0 onwards, so I think this is a Lua question. Unless you have some empirical evidence that running your Lua code is noticeably slower when run by Redis than when run directly by Lua.

Comment: define "expensive"